# Vue reactivity doesn't pick up new property added to element in a array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

Not sure if I am explaining this right, but I am facing an issue where one of my template elements isn't reacting to added property of an array element. For example:

```
<div v-for="user in users"
     v-bind:key="user.id"
     v-bind:name="user.name">
     {{user.name}}
     <div class="warn" v-if="user.hasWarning">Warning!</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to display the warning whenever `hasWarning: true` is added to `user`

```
data:() {
  users: [
    {id: 1, name: "Foo"}
  ]
},
methods:{
  showWarning: function(id) {
    users.forEach(user => {
      if (user.id == id) {
        user.hasWarning = true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I tried calling `showWarning(id)` and I do see `hasWarning` added to user from both console and Vue developer tools, but it doesn't render `<div class class="warn" v-if="user.hasWarning"..`. If I have my user set up as `{id: 1, name: "foo", hasWarning: false}`, it seems to work fine, but why it is not working for added property? Should I avoid it entirely?

Comment: +1 @Gabriel's answer, plus It's considered a better practice to use the strict equality (===)  in place of `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to use the method `this.$set` to register new properties. See in documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set

Try something like that:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="user in users" v-bind:key="user.id" v-bind:name="user.name">
      {{ user.name }}
      <button @click="showWarning(user.id)">showWarning</button>
      <div class="warn" v-if="user.hasWarning">Warning!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    users: [{ id: 1, name: 'Foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'Bar' }],
  }),
  methods: {
    showWarning(id) {
      let user = this.users.find(user => user.id == id);
      this.$set(user, 'hasWarning', true);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```